# Possible to modify @ModelAttribute before @Validated is run

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Is is possible to modify a @ModelAttribute before it is validated via @Validated.

ie

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final ModelAndView save(
        @Validated(value = {myGroup.class}) @ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject)
```

I need to change the state of myObject before @Validated is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about add a ModelAttribute populate method?

```
@ModelAttribute("myObject")
public MyObject modifyBeforeValidate(
        @ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject) {
    //modify it here
    return myObject;
}
```

The side affect is this method will be invoked before every @RequestMapping method if I'm not mistaken.

Update1: example

```
@ModelAttribute("command")
public ChangeOrderCommand fillinUser(
        @ModelAttribute("command") ChangeOrderCommand command,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    command.setUser(securityGateway.getUserFrom(request));
    return command;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String change(@ModelAttribute("command") ChangeOrderCommand command,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, Locale locale) {
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that this would only happen for a RequestMethod.GET request

Comment: @jax I found an example in my previous project. see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to modify the model attribute object before the `@Validated` will trigger:

1. Remove `@Validated` and autowire the validator and manually trigger the validator:

```
class MyController {

  private final Validator validator;

  class MyController(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  @PostMapping("/doSomething")
  public final ModelAndView save(
        @ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject, BindingResult result) {
    // edit MyObject here

    validator.validate(myObject, result)

    // original method body here
}
```

2. Decorate the default validator and pre-process the `myObject` object inside the decorated validator.

```
class MyController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new PreProcessMyObjectValidator(binder.getValidator()));
    }

@PostMapping("/doSomething")
  public final ModelAndView save(
        @Validated(value = {myGroup.class}) @ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject, BindingResult result) {
    ...
  } 

private static class PreProcessMyObjectValidator implements Validator {
        private final Validator validator;

        public PreProcessMyObjectValidator(Validator validator) {
            this.validator = validator;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(@Nonnull Class<?> clazz) {
            return validator.supports(clazz);
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(@Nonnull Object target, @Nonnull Errors errors) {
            if (target instanceof MyObject) {
                MyObject myObject = (MyObject) target;
                // manipulate myObject here

            }

            validator.validate(target, errors);
        }
    }

}
```

(This second tip is what I picked up from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11103)