# Spring MVC @ModelAttribute method

Tags: spring-mvc, modelattribute

Question about `Spring MVC` `@ModelAttribute` methods, Setting model attributes in a controller `@RequestMapping` method verses setting attribute individually with `@ModelAttribute` methods, which one is considered better and is more used?

From design point of view which approach is considered better from the following:

Approach 1

```
@ModelAttribute("message")
public String addMessage(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, ModelMap model) {

  LOGGER.info("addMessage - " + userName);
  return "Spring 3 MVC Hello World - "  + userName;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/welcome/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, ModelMap model) {

  LOGGER.info("printWelcome - " + userName);
  return "hello";
}
```

Approach 2

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, ModelMap model) {

  LOGGER.info("printWelcome - " + userName);

  model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World - "  + userName);

  return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One is not better then the other. They both serve another purpose.

- **Method:** If you need the model for a particular controller to be always populated with certain attributes the method level `@ModelAttribute` makes more sense.
- **Parameter:** Use it on a parameter when you want to bind data from the request and add it to the model implicitly.

#### To answer your question on the better approach

I would say approach 2 is better since the data is specific to that handler.

Comment: Ok I see. So when the data is specific to handler approach-2 is better and when data is generic and could be used by multiple handlers within the controller, then approach-1 is better. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 22):

The `@ModelAttribute annotation` serves two purposes depending on how it is used:

**At Method level**

Use `@ModelAttribute` at the method level to provide reference data for the model. @ModelAttribute annotated methods are executed before the chosen `@RequestMapping` annotated handler method. They effectively pre-populate the implicit model with specific attributes, often loaded from a database. Such an attribute can then already be accessed through `@ModelAttribute` annotated handler method parameters in the chosen handler method, potentially with binding and validation applied to it.

In other words; a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` will populate the specified “key” in the model. This happens BEFORE the `@RequestMapping`
At Method Parameter level

**At Method Parameter level**

When you place `@ModelAttribute` on a method parameter, `@ModelAttribute` maps a model attribute to the specific, annotated method parameter. This is how the controller gets a reference to the object holding the data entered in the form.

**Examples**

**Method Level**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @ModelAttribute("productsList")
    public Collection<Product> populateProducts() {
        return this.productsService.getProducts();
    }
   }
```

So, in the above example, “`productsList`” in the Model is populated before the the `@RequestMapping` is performed.

**Method parameter level**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("product") Product myProduct, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

        new ProductValidator().validate(myProduct, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "productForm";
        }
        else {
            this.productsService.saveProduct(myProduct);
            status.setComplete();
            return "productSaved";
        }
    }
}
```

Look [**here**](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-modelattribute-annotation-works-in.html) for detailed information with examples.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have refined the question further, please provide your views.

Comment: @KamalKishore Please have a look at my answer, link added.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it explains pretty well the flow for ModelAttribute. Am tempted to go through your other blogs as well.

Comment: shouldn't your attention be `@modelAttribute("productsList")` in the `processSubmit` method?